# parsing a string for markups and converting it to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im wondering if this is possible. I am currently using `react-mentions` to create a mention like feature similar to those found on social media platforms. So far i have gotten it to work. However im having an issue.

**The Problem**

Im saving the entire textfield area to database. This includes the markup symbols . Therefore , when rendering it in the front end as a Text , the markup symbols are showing.

Heres an example of what it looks like :

[image]

With that being said , I feel like i have 2 ways to go about this :

1. Remove the symbols before saving it in database
2. Somehow detect the markup symbols and 'append' a react wrapper component over it so that it looks nicer.

Im more inclined towards option 2. If it was possible , i would want to wrap it in a react component made from the package `antd` , called `tags` .

**Question summarized**

1. Is there a way to easily remove the markups from the text?
2. Is there a way to identify the markups in string format and somehow place a react wrapper around it?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase some are looking for an answer , i used a package called :

```
react-string-replace
```

[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace)

Usage:

```
                <Text>Content : 
            {reactStringReplace(selected_task.content, /@\[(.*?)]/g, (match, i) => (
                <Tag color="geekblue" key={i}>{match}</Tag>
            ))}
    </Text>
```